# how to call json within create session in rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a log in page for a website in rails. I was trying to send a json request if the password is wrong. the code checks if the password is wrong but does not log in if it is right.This is my code

```
#sessions_controller.rb
def create
     user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

     if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to welcome_landing_page_path, :notice => "Logged in!"
        flash[:success]= "Successfully Logged In"
    else
        respond_to do |format|

        format.json{render :json => !!@user}


        end
    end

end
def index
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged out!"

end
```

This is my js file from where my wrong password message will be displayed

```
#signin_valid.js
function LoginUserForm(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod("email_format", function(value, element) {
    return /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test( value );
});


$('#signin_user').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {

        "email": {
            required: true,
            email_format: true,
            remote:"/sessions/check_email"
        },
        "password":{
            required: true,
            remote:"/sessions/create"
        }
    },
errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    messages: {

        "email": {
            required: "Email can't be blank.",
            email_format: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com.",
            remote: "This email id does not exists"
        },
        "password": {
            required: "Please enter the password",
            remote:"Wrong Password"
        }

    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().parent().removeClass("has-error");
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {

// 'this' refers to the form
var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
if (errors) {
// Populating error message
var errorMessage = errors == 1
? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
: 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
// Removing the form error if it already exists
$("#div_user_js_validation_error").remove();
errorHtml = "<div id='div_user_js_validation_error' class=\"alert alert-danger\" data-alert=\"alert\" style=\"margin-bottom:5px;\">"+ errorMessage +"</div>"
$("#div_modal_generic div.modal-body-main").prepend(errorHtml);
// Show error labels
$("div.error").show();
} else {
// Hide error labels
$("div.error").hide();
// Removing the error message
$("#div_user_js_validation_error").remove();
}
},


submitHandler: function(form) {
form.submit();
}
});

}
```

Comment: Please show us your `user.authenticate` or tell us what Authentication gem you are using.

Comment: i want to create a flash message for wrong password but it should not redirect to any other page. If i don't render or redirect then i get a template missing error

Comment: i have used has_secure_password in model